# fast pytables pandas data slicing

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I am suffering from slow running speed. 
my data is

```
 <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
 File path: c:/data/bed_1/acc_ohlc.hdf
 /000020            frame        (shape->[7721,5])
 /000030            frame        (shape->[1037,5])
 /000040            frame        (shape->[7723,5])
 /000050            frame        (shape->[7723,5])
 /000060            frame        (shape->[7723,5])
 /000070            frame        (shape->[7724,5])
 /000080            frame        (shape->[2426,5])
```

each are pandas data frame and each data length is different.
index are timestamp. 
for making new data set which have all same period data.

```
  begin = '20140117'
  end = '20150116'   
  p_data = {}
  for index, row in code_list.iterrows():
      code = row['Code'][:-3]
      p_data[code] = store[code].ix[begin:end].astype (float)
  new_data = pd.Panel(p_data)
```

new_data = pd.Panel (p_data)

Total running time is around 25 second. 
is there any good code to shorten running time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might speed up the process drastically.
.iterrows may not be the best option out there.

```
def fun(c):
   code = c[:-3]
   p_data[code] = store[code].ix[begin:end].astype (float)

code_list.Code.apply(fun)
```

Comment: thanks altunyurt. I tried your suggested code. but there is no progress. running time is almost same. around 22 sec.